# Docker Image move to the src directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So , I have a project and I want to have a docker image for the project. My directory is:

```
    --Dockerfile
    --source
```

So in my Dockerfile I have commands like :

1. COPY source  /source
2. RUN cd source
   The image is built fine , but when I run the container the last statement cd source is not executed.

PS. I tried using WORKDIR instead of RUN cd , but then the contents of the source was not copied. 
Any work-around so that the statement cd source is executed on its own?

Comment: What process are you trying to run in the container?

Comment: I build an image from this dockerfile using " docker build"  and then I run the container  using "docker run". Note : This is not the final dockerfile , after executing RUN cd source , I have other commands that I will add to my dockerfile , which finally will startup my application in the container.

Comment: Did you tried using `WORKDIR /source`?

Comment: WORKDIR /source made my day :)

Comment: see my answer for full doc ref as well

Comment: @amrx, feel free to accept answers and close the questions as answered...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `WORKDIR` command to set work directory through Dockerfile, you can change workdir as part of `docker run` with the command switch `-w`

see full docs for reference: http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#workdir

and the docker run switch: http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#workdir